# Free load testing tool for Silverlight

Tags: windows, gratis

Do you know some free tool that allows load testing of a Silverlight application? After searching at web I know that two good free load testing tools are [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/), but I am not sure if they work good with a Silverlight application.

For now I pretend to do only whole-app (system) testing, but if I see it worth to do unit load testing, I will consider it too.

I have to test the response time of several features in the client (the Silverlight app), including the search engine. For that, I still don't know what is the the better approach. I don't know if, for example, the better approach would be to simulate traffic on the server or just altering the responsiveness of the server and determine the impact of server-side slowdowns on the client. The system must support at least 300 users.

After that, I would like to perform stress testing as well, although it is not a essential thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you are looking for I would recommend [LoadUIWeb](http://loaduiweb.org/), it has **support for SilverLight** depending on what protocol the application is using. If your familiar with SoapUI, Java or Groovy than it's scripting language is easy to learn.

The LoadUI community is rather small though (LoadTesting in general is though) but since SoapUI and LoadUI is similar in a lot of ways, their community will be able to assist in a lot of ways.

For explanation of LoadUIWeb for SilverLight please check [this](http://loaduiweb.org/docs/generalinformation/supportedapps/ria/applications/support-for-silverlight-applications.html)